# EF, WinForms. Bind navigation property to DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagrid

I'm following this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-PL/data/jj682076. I want to load particular category from my Context, then create a DataGrid and bind it with Products property of this category. I want to be able to add, edit, and remove products on the DataGrid
I have been trying with this code:

```
context.Cetegories.Where(c => c.categoryID == _category.categoryID ).Select(c => c.Products).Load();
this.productsBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Categories.Local.ToBindingList();
```

where `productsBindingSource` is my binding source and DataGrid is generated by the designer with binding source as DataSource.
How can I achieve this?
I thought also about to load the products straight from the context and bind them to DataGrid

```
_context.Products.Where(c => c.categoryID == _category.categoryID).Load();
```

but then when i want to add new product for that category straight from the grid there is the problem with fk, because i don't know how to set it properly for the new item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. Earlier code for load the products for category was correct. The problem was that this code returns an object of `Category` type and to obtain from it `products` navigation property i had to use another binding source with `Category` as `DataSource`. After that i could use a `productBingindSource` with `DataSource` set to the new bs and `DataMember` property set to `products` navigation property of new bs. This finally allowed me to bind products of particular Category with DataGrid.